# Vue cli 3 and IE 11

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have Vue cli 3.0.0-rc.10. We use TypeScript3 in class style. I want use IE11. I see error in IE 11, about not support arrow function in sl-vue-tree plugin.

I tried

```
// babel.config.js
process.env.VUE_CLI_BABEL_TRANSPILE_MODULES = true;

module.exports = {
    "presets": [
        [
            "@vue/app",
            {
                "useBuiltIns": "entry",
            }
        ]
    ]
}
```

and import ‘@babel/polyfill’; in enter file - **not work**

Only work

```
// vue.config.js
module.exports = {
transpileDependencies:[
‘sl-vue-tree’,
]
};
```

Now in production mode all is Ok, but i got error in development mode "export ‘default’ (imported as ‘SlVueTree’) was not found in ‘sl-vue-tree’

How solve problem?

Comment: How are you importing this package? It would seem as if you should do `import * as SlVueTree from 'sl-vue-tree'`. and not `import SlVueTree from 'sl-vue-tree`

Comment: Got error `Failed to mount component: template or render function not defined.`

Comment: Am I right in thinking `"export ‘default’ (imported as ‘SlVueTree’) was not found in ‘sl-vue-tree’` is a compiler warning?  I am having a [similar issue](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues/2637#issuecomment-425403329).